# No tags for Danmaku (Bullet Hell) games genre, mess with Touhou tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I was looking for questions regarding Touhou Project games, [even asked one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214840/what-is-shotslow-in-touhou-7-perfect-cherry-blossom-ver-1-00b), but had problem tagging it. There is no tag for Touhou games, but there are tags for:

- [touhou-eosd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-eosd),
- [touhou-7.5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-7.5), and after posting my question, [mathias711](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/80141/mathias711) added tag for my game:
- [touhou-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-7)

But there are more than 20 Touhou games, should we keep adding tags for every single one of them when a question appears?

In addition to Touhou, there are many other Danmaku (弾幕, literally bullet curtain or curtain fire) games, often called also Bullet Hell games. I was searching, but couldn't find any tag relating to these games genre, except occasional tag. If there is none, maybe it should be added?

Touhou games are getting more and more popular nowadays amongst Western people, especially thanks to fandom, official (and doujinshi) manga, as well as Osu! content. I think there will be more that less questions regarding Danmaku games, so there could be added proper tag corresponding this genre, as well as one more general Touhou tag.

What do You think about these suggestions, are they worth fulfilling?

Comment: Note that you unlock the ability to dynamically create tags as you write questions at only the 300 reputation mark - it only takes a bare minimum of site participation to get that privilege.  Then you can create the genre tag and the game tag if they're missing.  Note a very old meta post:  http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/674/tagging-those-shmups-with-lots-and-lots-of-pretty-bullets?rq=1

Comment: Please ignore my answer if you saw it, as well my remark above about the genre tag.  I forgot that this site typically doesn't use genre tags - not my only active site, others prefer it, lol.  There are uses for genre tags here, but not enough that every game question should have one - Arqade prefers genre tags (like platform tags) only be used if a question is actually about the entire genre (or platform), not just because a particular game happens to fit in that genre.  If there's a game-specific tag, the genre tag is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

To address the point of when tags should be created: **Tags only exist when they are attached to questions**.

They are automatically purged from the system if they have no questions, which may be the case after a question using a singular tag is deleted (or edited to no longer contain the tag).

---

On the point about the Touhou games, at the moment, there are less than 10 questions between the different Touhou tags - I'd be happy to leave the tags as they are for the time being - we prefer each game to have a singular tag anyway, and I don't think it's terrible enough at this time to warrant merging.

It's easier to merge tags later if they start getting out of hand, then it is to sift through and recreate them if we decide they shouldn't be merged.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, you are right about having different tags for different games, especially if there were no questions regarding them - who needs phantom tags? From the other hand, what do you think about Bullet Hell games genre tag?  There are questions about other games of this kind, like http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203312/what-does-grazing-do or http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203311/how-do-i-increase-my-point-multiplier , which can be helpful for players from other games, as general rules are usually similar or almost the same.

Comment: @Kusavil - if you have questions that are general in nature to the entire genre, ask them and create a genre tag. I don't think those two questions qualify as they are asking about functionality as it pertains to specific games. Do note that our existing genre tags are only used for high-level questions, specific mechanic questions as they relate to two or more games are tagged with those games instead

Answer (score 1):

I think we should have a tag for each game. Especially when it gets more popular, we need to divide it into different categories, as some tactics, game elements or mechanics *can* change between different games.